# How to create a scratch file in pycharm for Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I can create a scratch file from menu "Tools" -> "New Scratch File...".

But Django settings and environment variables are not imported automatically. Is there a way to do that now or this feature is just meant for pure python code testing.

I want to be able to

```
from website.models import *
```

but I get this error

```
File "/Users/user1/.virtualenvs/test-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
% (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
```

Thanks

Comment: That's not the entire Exception.

Comment: true. it is common exception that you get when you try to access django classes from python without loading django environment variables. PyCharm has 2 type of debug environment. one for pure python and one for django where it loads all the django variables automatically for you. I guess they have not done this for Scratch files. Maybe they will let you create django scratch files in the future.

Comment: In PyCharm you have the default python shell and then there's the shell from Django's manage.py (command: `manage.py shell`). What you're trying to achieve can be done using some workarounds, basically you want to use Django in a simple python script. The procedure is different for most Django versions, but take a look at [this blog entry](http://blog.gabrielsaldana.org/using-django-models-in-external-python-scripts/), do some google research and you'll make it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Leistungsabfall, here is a working solution :-)

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append(os.path.join('/Users/user1/gitroot/website1/web', 'myproject'))

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
from django.conf import settings

from website.models import *
```

Answer (score 5):

You should not need to add anything to sys.path. This works for Python 3.7+, Django 2.1+ and PyCharm 2019+:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "APPNAMEHERE.settings")

import django
django.setup()
```

Add this at the top of your scratch-file to have access to a Django app. Futher info on [ImproperlyConfigured-error](https://andreasbergstrom.com/posts/pycharm-scratch-files-django/).